# How to interact with the share popup in chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, video-capture

I am trying to automate recording of some tabs at the same time. I tried using an extension called scre.io or (screen recorder) and it is awesome. It can capture multiple tabs at the same times with each one only recording its own audio but there was one problem, I can't automate the part where I choose which tab to be recorded:

[image]

is there any way for this to work, I tried using AutoIt but it also couldn't interact with this popup. if there are any alternatives, I would appreciate it.